# Upgrading boost caused slow debug builds

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, build, performance

After upgrading from Boost 1.47.0 to 1.50.0 our build times exploded for the debug builds. They now take approx. 3 times longer while the release builds are somewhat slower but not a lot. We use VS2010 in combination with Teamcity for building.

Anybody have a clue where this is coming from? From what I see in the build logs every project that uses Boost is building a lot slower, it doesn't seem related to a specific part of Boost. We do precompile the Boost headers.

I had to increase the memory available for precompiling in some projects using the -Zm compiler option so that indicates at least that more memory is needed than before. Our build agents seem to have enough memory though. I did notice that the compiler (cl.exe) doesn't use a lot of CPU time (5-10%) which may indicate slowness getting the header files from the network but I don't see why this has changed a lot when upgrading Boost versions.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What boost libraries do you use?

Comment: We use various libraries in different projects. Too much to mention here.